# Understanding Perl one-liner with -p, -i, and -e switches

Tags: perl

There is a perl script which is already existing in one of the modules and i would like to understand/know how its working and the meaning of the arguments passed.

I tried to find the description of the arguments passed online however I could not find any good resource which explains it.

```
perl -p -i -e 's/ÿ//g' filename
```

Please help in understanding the workflow.

Comment: [`perldoc perlrun`](https://metacpan.org/pod/perlrun#Command-Switches)

Comment: Read the perl command line docs? http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- `-p` implies a loop similar to this around the code in quotes: `while(<>){ ..... } continue{print}`.
- `-i` implies "in place edit", meaning that each logical record (typically a line) that you change will result in a change in that line in the file.
- `-e` means evaluate the string that follows as code and execute it.  Since you are using `-p`, the string of code is executed within in implicit while loop, as mentioned above.
- `s///` is the substitution operator. It acts upon the content of `$_` unless it is bound to some other scalar using `=~`. Your implicit 'while' loop populates `$_` with one record from the input file per iteration (in this case, one line from the input file per iteration).  So in each line you are substituting the `ÿ` character for an empty string (in other words, deleting that character) every time it appears in the line.

You should use `perldoc` to explore Perl's built in documentation on the following topics:

- `perldoc perlintro` - A brief introduction to Perl.
- `perldoc perlretut` - A tutorial on Perl's regular expressions.
- `perldoc perlre` - A more in-depth description of Perl's regular expressions.
- `perldoc perlrun` - An explanation of Perl's command-line switches such as `-p`, `-e`, and so on.
- `perldoc perlop` - An explanation of Perl's operators, including `<>`, and `s///`.
- `perldoc -f print` - Description of how Perl's `print` function works (it is implied by `-p`).
- `perldoc -f defined`
- `perldoc -f readline`
- `perldoc perlsyn` - A description of Perl's syntax including `while(){}` loops (`-p` implies a while loop).

If you put all that together, that one liner does something pretty close to this:

```
BEGIN { $^I = ""; }                   # Set in-place edit mode.
our $oldargv = '';                    # Placeholder or sentinel flag.
while (defined($_ = readline ARGV)) { # ARGV will be the currently
                                      # opened file from commandline.
    if ($ARGV ne $oldargv) {
        open ARGVOUT, '>$ARGV';       # Open an output file; same name
                                      # as input file, but ARGV still
                                      # reads from original.
        select ARGVOUT;               # Output goes to ARGVOUT.
        $oldargv = $ARGV;             # Keep track of what filename we
                                      # are reading from.
    }

    $_ =~ s/ÿ//g;                     # Do our work... substitute.

}
continue {
    print $_;                         # After each iteration print the
                                      # content of $_ to ARGVOUT.
}
END {
    select STDOUT;
    close ARGVOUT;
}
```

This is an approximate representation cobbled together by using the Perl module B::Deparse as well as a dive into Perl's documentation. Perl's documentation is extensive, and available on any system with a standard installation of Perl on it. You can read Perl's documentation by entering at the commandline: `perldoc perl####` where `####` represents the document name. Example: `perldoc perldata`.  If you want to look up a specific Perl function you would use the `-f` switch, as in `perldoc -f open`.  And if you want to read the documentation on a Perl module, you would type `perldoc ModuleName` (eg, `perldoc Scalar::Util`).

Comment: Thanks for the edit. It was really helpful in understanding the concept. Currently going through the documentations.